# How to command "Head north" in German naval/military slang?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, imperative

I have recently bought a board game where you play the role of a
submarine captain and you have to instruct your crew to move the
submarine in one direction: north, south, east or west.

This game can be played in any language and I usually play it in
English, so the captain gives orders saying "Head North!".

To make the game a little bit more difficult for the other team, I
thought about each team playing in a different language. And since
some of my friends are German, this is the option preferred after
English.

When I asked my friends how they would translate "Head north", they came
up with some options:

- Kurs Nord
- Richtung Norden
- Segeln Norden

My question here is: which will be the best translation to give the
orders in German?

It is supposed to be a military submarine captain giving orders, so
it should be some naval/military slang and the orders should be given
in imperative (the captain is not asking to go north, he is
commanding to do so!).

Also should it be *Nord* or *Norden*?

Comment: You might want to watch "Das Boot". German war drama about submarine U-96 during World War II. I think next to a full documentary or joining the navy this might be the next best thing to getting military style commands on a german submarine... although there are some points of criticism about how the actors portray the german sub crew.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Formally, course is not commanded using compass directions (north, south, east, west) in mil-speak, too long and too easy to mis-interpret. You rather give the course in degrees, 0° heading north, going clockwise 90° east, 180° south and so on. So in a proper military order, the terminology would be

> Neuer Kurs: 0 Grad!

Or, even more snappy:

> Kurs 000! (null-null-null)

See here: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kommandos_in_der_Schifffahrt

*[Neuer] Kurs Nord!* and *Richtung Norden!* would be fine, *auf Nordkurs gehen* as well, but don't really sound *professional*. The "German friend", however, who proposed "Segeln Norden" should undergo a thorough background check - He might be spying for some foreign power, because that is definitely not German.

Comment: +1 deserved for the last two sentences ^_^

Comment: Also, "segeln" is specifically the act of navigating a ship with sails, so it's completely nonsensical on a submarine.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful answer. By the way if someone was curious about which game I'm talking about, it's a board game called Captain Sonar.

Comment: If I recall my "commands to the helm" from my time in the US navy you'd generally give a rudder direction, a rudder amount, and a course - so something like "Helmsman! Left standard rudder, steady new course 000" would be a typical command. In German I think this would be something along the lines of "Steuermann! Linke Standard Ruder, stetig neue Kurs 000".

Comment: All German players I ever saw/heard playing *Captain Sonar* just said the direction (Nord, Ost, Süd, West) without any command word like *head* or anything else like that.